# Is it possible to have an edit/update route without `/:id` in the url in node.js?

Tags: node.js, routes

Currently, the only way I learned to get the users info from a database is by having their :id in the route and req.params.id

```
// GET USER DETAILS
router.get("/:id/profile-setting", middleware.isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
    User.findById(req.params.id, function (err, foundUser) {
        res.render("membership/profile-setting", {
            user: foundUser
        });
    });
});
```

Is it possible to just have `router.get("/profile-setting")` and still be able to get the logged in users data from the database without having the :id in the route?

I'm asking because it is kind of strange to have the users :id in the url and it would be easier for the user to look up the link in the future without having to type out a huge :id.

Comment: What are you using to authenticate user ? get id from there, it can be in session or token

Comment: @georoot I'm `req.isAuthenticated()` from passport.js and I think that is checking for a session.

Comment: Usually i use token , not sure about passport.js but you can look at the docs to find how you can get the current user.

Comment: @georoot all I needed to do was pass `req.user` instead of finding it by id etc. so the solution is `res.render("membership/profile-setting", {
            user: req.user
        });`

Comment: ^^^ which is exactly what i said above. Oh i see by `docs` i meant documentation of nodejs not mongodb docs